# How does CPU distinguish between kernel code and user space code?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

I have come across notions of Kernel space and user space. Kernel code has data and functions which cannot be accessed from user space. How exactly does CPU distinguish if the code its running is kernel ? I know CPU sets some kernel mode bit for kernel code execution but what exactly in the code prompts it to set the kernel mode bit.

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406908/457018

Comment: Also, you might be interested in looking at the context switch code in Linux, [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L5255).

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to that question depends on CPU architecture, but in general it is like this:

The CPU enters the kernel mode in those cases:

- On power-on or reset. The CPU jumps to a special reset address.
- On hardware interrupt. The CPU saves the address of the current instruction, the current status and mode, and jumps to a predefined handler address.
- On exceptional situation (page fault, unknown instruction, etc). The CPU saves current status and jumps to a predefined address.
- On a special instruction: "TRAP" or "SYSCALL" or similar. Again, the CPU saves status and jumps to a predefined address.

You may notice, that when CPU enters the kernel mode - it always jumps to some predefined address. Moreover, those addresses can only be changed while in kernel mode - the user program is never allowed to decide the destination. The kernel completely controls all entry points into the kernel mode.

The user mode can be entered with a special instruction. Usually, this instruction also does the jump, but this time it allows to choose the destination.